# How to get queryset with at least one of ForeignKey objects attributes specified?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models related with foreign key.

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    # some attributes

class GalleryPhoto(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='photos')
    approved = models.BooleanField('approved', default=False)
```

I want to get a queryset of `Gallery` objects that are related with at least one approved photo. I know how to get objects, where all of the photos are approved, but it's not what I want to achieve:

```
Gallery.objects.filter(photos__approved=True)
```

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your example does exactly what you asked for

```
Gallery.objects.filter(photos__approved=True)
```

Returns Gallery objects that are related with at least one approved photo.

To return Galleries where **all** of the photos are approved, you have to write

`Gallery.objects.filter(photos__approved=True).exclude(photos__approved=False)`

Comment: Oh, you're right! My bad! I was almost sure that the problem was here. It was actually in the other part of my code. Anyway, thank you !